# rubocop cannot load such file -- rubocop-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rubocop

I installed the gem [rubocop](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/rubocop). When I run:
command
`rubocop`
terminal responds:

```
longnguyen:~/RubyOnRails/project$ rubocop
cannot load such file -- rubocop-rails
/home/sun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/rubocop-0.72.0/lib/rubocop/config_loader_resolver.rb:15:in `require'
/home/sun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/rubocop-0.72.0/lib/rubocop/config_loader_resolver.rb:15:in `block in resolve_requires'
/home/sun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/rubocop-0.72.0/lib/rubocop/config_loader_resolver.rb:11:in `each'
/home/sun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/rubocop-0.72.0/lib/rubocop/config_loader_resolver.rb:11:in `resolve_requires'
/home/sun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/rubocop-0.72.0/lib/rubocop/config_loader.rb:45:in `load_file'
/home/sun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/rubocop-0.72.0/lib/rubocop/config_loader.rb:86:in `configuration_from_file'
/home/sun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/rubocop-0.72.0/lib/rubocop/config_store.rb:44:in `for'
/home/sun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/rubocop-0.72.0/lib/rubocop/cli.rb:242:in `apply_default_formatter'
/home/sun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/rubocop-0.72.0/lib/rubocop/cli.rb:50:in `run'
/home/sun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/rubocop-0.72.0/exe/rubocop:13:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/sun/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
/home/sun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/rubocop-0.72.0/exe/rubocop:12:in `<top (required)>'
/home/sun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/bin/rubocop:23:in `load'
/home/sun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/bin/rubocop:23:in `<main>'
/home/sun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
/home/sun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'
```

Help me, please!

Comment: Can you add full log?

Comment: Hi bro, updated!!

Comment: try to add .rubocop.yml file in project

Comment: I'm using  .rubocop.yml :(. It's not ok

Comment: use `gem 'rubocop', require: false`, don't have any other option.

Comment: It's not running :((

Answer (score 10):

Seems like you have something like: 
`require: rubocop-rails` somewhere in your rubocop configuration files chain. But you have not included `gem 'rubocop-rails'` in your gemfile.

Please include gem 'rubocop-rails' in your gemfile and this should be resolved.

Comment: That's Ok. However I want use gem 'rubocop'? Can't u help me?

Comment: rubocop gem has been broken up in extensions, when you write `require: rubocop-someextension` in its yml configuration, you need to have that `rubocop-someextension` also installed. So in your case, either remove that require or if you need it include the extension gem.

Comment: I want to remove that require. But I don't know, can you support me?

Comment: Please edit your question and include the rubocop.yml file please. And if there is todo_rubocop.yml file share that as well. @longnguyễn

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar issue.
It was hard to detect because I already had `gem "rubocop-rails"` included into `Gemfile`.
The issue was related to some incompatibility between versions of `gem "rubocop"` and `gem "rubocop-rails"`.
These two commands helped me:

```bash
bundle update rubocop 
bundle install
```

I have updated `gem "rubocop"` to the latest version and it solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of rubocop-rails do you use?

In my case with 2.1.0 version was fine.

```
$ bundle update rubocop-rails
...
Installing rubocop-rails 2.1.0 (was 1.5.0)
Bundle updated!

$ bundle console
Frame number: 0/18
[1] pry(main)> require 'rubocop-rails'
=> true
```

Answer (score 0):

adding `gem 'rubocop-rails'` in my Gemfile under development group worked.